# Write text data to array between boundaries

Tags: python, arrays

I have a problem which i hope you can help me solve! I have a txt that looks like:

```
A100 1960  
 3   5  
 6   7  
 8   9  
 10  11  
 12  13  
A200 1960  
 3   5  
 6   7  
 8   9  
 10  11  
 12  13  
 14  15    
A300 1960  
 3   5  
 6   7  
 8   9  
 10  11  
 12  13  
 14  15  
 16  17
```

I want to search for the keyword for example `A200 1960`. Now I want to save all numbers between `A200 1960` and `A300 1960` in an `array(x, y)`.

I managed to skip to the line I want. The problem now is to write to the array until line  `A300 1960`. Also the length of the array can variate.

```
def readnumbers(filename,number,year):
    number_year = np.asarray([])

    f = open(filename)
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    strings_number = 'A'+ str(number)
    strings_year = ' ' + str(year)

    STARTER = strings_number+ '' + strings_year
    start_seen = False

    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() == STARTER:
            start_seen = True
            continue

        if start_seen == True:
            parts = line.split()
```

Comment: The indention of your Python code is not correct. Please [edit] your question so that we can see what is part of `readnumbers` and what is not.

Comment: @poke Are you sure this is the correct indention? Maybe ...

Comment: Thanks eveyone for helping me! I got it now. Really nice community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a standard `list` to store each line after you have set `start_seen`. And also check each line if it’s a “STOPPER” line so you can stop iterating the file.

Also:

- Make sure to return your result otherwise you don’t get anything.
- Use the `with` statement to open the file, so you don’t have to manually close it.
- Don’t use `readlines()` but instead iterate over the file handle directly.
- Don’t check `if variable == True:` but just do `if variable:`

```
def readnumbers(filename,number,year):
    strings_number = 'A'+ str(number)
    strings_year = ' ' + str(year)
    STARTER = strings_number + '' + strings_year

    result = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        start_seen = False

        # iterate the file handle
        for line in f:
            # only check the line for STARTER if you haven’t seen it yet
            if not start_seen and line.strip() == STARTER:
                start_seen = True

            # otherwise, check if it’s a stopper which starts with `A`
            elif start_seen and line.startswith('A'):
                break

            # otherwise, if we’ve seen the start line, we need to capture the result
            elif start_seen:
                parts = line.split()

                # append to the result list
                result.append(parts)

    # finally, return the result
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = 'test.txt'

def fill_array():
    f = open(filename)
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
    search_term = 'A200 1960'
    read = False
    array = []
    for index in xrange(0,len(lines)):
        if lines[index] == search_term:
            read = True
        elif read: 
            data =  [x.strip() for x in lines[index].split(' ') if x]
            if str(data[0]).isdigit(): 
                array.append(data)
            else: 
                read = False
    print array
```

Array will contain the numbers that you want to save
Output
`[['3', '5'], ['6', '7'], ['8', '9'], ['10', '11'], ['12', '13'], ['14', '15']]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys

start = sys.argv[2] # 'A200 1960'
end = sys.argv[3]   # 'A300 1960'

coords = []         # collected (x, y) tuples
start_seen = False  # Have we seen start yet?
end_seen = False    # Have we seen end yet?

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for row in f:
        if row.startswith(start):
            start_seen = True
            continue
        if row.startswith(end):
            end_seen = True
            continue
        if start_seen and not end_seen:
            # Split the line and convert each part into an int.
            x, y = [int(s) for s in row.split()]
            coords.append((x, y))

print(coords)
```

Usage:

```
$ python3.4 so.py data.csv 'A200 1960' 'A300 1960'
```

Output:

```
[(3, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9), (10, 11), (12, 13), (14, 15)]
```